# exception : noHttpResponse in android

Tags: android

here posting data to url and getting response from it.but now getting noHttpResponse exception 
here placing code

```
TextView xx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xx);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(
            "http://motinfo.direct.gov.uk/internet/jsp/ECHID-Internet-History-Request.jsp");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
        nameValuePairs
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "Vehicle registration mark from number plate",
                        "123456789"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MOT test number",
                "AP3398"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MOT test number",
                "000000"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        String line = "";
        if (response != null) {
            System.out
                    .println("***********************************************************");
            xx.setText(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here adding logcat

```
   09-11 12:40:22.086: I/InputDispatcher(61): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}.  640698.7ms since event, 640698.2ms since wait started
09-11 12:40:22.086: I/WindowManager(61): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}
09-11 12:40:27.117: I/InputDispatcher(61): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}.  645729.5ms since event, 645728.9ms since wait started
09-11 12:40:27.117: I/WindowManager(61): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}
09-11 12:40:32.165: I/InputDispatcher(61): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}.  650777.7ms since event, 650777.1ms since wait started
09-11 12:40:32.165: I/WindowManager(61): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}
09-11 12:40:37.182: I/InputDispatcher(61): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}.  655793.8ms since event, 655793.3ms since wait started
09-11 12:40:37.183: I/WindowManager(61): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}
09-11 12:40:42.202: I/InputDispatcher(61): Application is not responding: AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}.  660814.3ms since event, 660813.7ms since wait started
09-11 12:40:42.202: I/WindowManager(61): Input event dispatching timed out sending to application AppWindowToken{406a9208 token=HistoryRecord{4064bf48 com.example.xxx/.MainActivity}}
```

Comment: You are facing `ANR` status, and due to this there might be exception, all of this might from slow internet connection or due to heavy `JSON` data you are getting from response.

Comment: have you tested on device?

Answer (score 0):

You should extract that piece of code which performs the http request into a method and execute it in a separate thread, for example using a `AsyncTask` or `IntentService`.

Starting with Android 3.0 and higher you are no longer allowed to perform network operations from the UI thread, otherwise a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown.

For Android 2.x you won't get that exception, but the http operation might take too long to execute and block the UI thread as a result, which may produce an ANR (application not responding) error, which seems to be your case.

Comment: Then you'll get Application Not Responding error. To fix this you should make the http request from a thread.

Answer (score 0):

By your log, I can see that the UI Thread is blocking because you are sending a POST request which blocks the App waiting for the response.

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for all http requests.